# How can I resolve 'ImportError: libCharLS.so.2: cannot open shared object file' on SLES 15 SP4 when libcharls2 is already installed?

Tags: python, opencv, jpeg, sles

ImportError: libCharLS.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

I am using SLES 15 SP4 and I have libcharls2 already installed. I read somewhere that I need to set the LD_LIBRARY_PATH of libCharLS.so.2 but when I try to find the location of shared library, I cannot find it.